# Migrate to GNUmake

Tags: makefile, migration, gnu-make

I have a proprietary build utility that builds a bunch of objects and executable across different directories.  I want to migrate to GNUmake.  Are there any tools that will parse the log files from previous build and construct makefiles?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool like that.  Even if it were available, it would likely create the stupidest possible result: every target hard-coded as a different explicit rule, with no use of pattern rules or variables to simplify.

Comment: @MadScientist: Well, to be fair, if it were smart enough to deduce intended targets and infer prerequisites (in the general case!), then it would certainly be smart enough to simplify its own rules. And it could probably serve as a pretty good system administrator, too.

Comment: I was thinking more like, something that can recognize the standard compiler format (`-o` followed by target, plus standard `-c` flag and source file names like `xxx.c` or `xxx.cpp`, and could convert that into an explicit rule.  Creating a map of regexs that can match various compiler rule commands would not take very long.  I could probably write the thing in Perl in less than 20 lines plus regex's (sorry, I'm a Perl guy.  Sue me.)  Anything more complex gets exponentially more difficult the more you want to do (match common compile commands to set variables, etc. etc.)

Comment: Thanks PS
Any other suggestions to simplify the migration is appreciated.

Comment: Are you free to try different/all targets? Do you know what all the targets are? Then I think you could actually rebuild the dependency graph. From there, just implement that graph in GNU Make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an easy way to do this, mainly because, I'm guessing, your build scripts are exactly that, scripts, written in an imperative fashion, whereas make is declarative (like Prolog), which is a real shift in mindset.

If you're using GCC (and I think GreenHills or Intel), you can have the compiler generate dependency information for you automatically. See the `-MD` and related options in the GCC manual.

These will potentially give you some hints as to what's going on, but ultimately, you just need to sit down and work out what's going on and translate that into make syntax; the [make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is actually pretty good - just make sure you *start* by doing a heirarchical build (i.e., do **not** use `make -C` in your Makefiles), as recursive make systems make it almost impossible to track dependencies reliably (I've yet to see one that does).